# Is there an example where pseudo-authentication via oAuth fails?

Tags: authentication, oauth

OAuth should not be used for authentication, even though it [sometimes is](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID#OpenID_vs._pseudo-authentication_using_OAuth) (Twitter explicitly [suggests to](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/faq)).

Are there good (realistic) examples where this pseudo-authentication paradigm fails?